# How to prepare ./configure make make install for my C file when it has other dependencies?

Tags: c, windows, makefile, centos, autoconf

Writing/reading code seems less stress then preparing a deploy scripts such as ./configure then make and make install for my C application's. How can i make a ./configure file and make files for this following C code? Thank you for your valuable support.

```
@file: main.c:

#include <ptlib.h>
#include <ptlib/video.h>

#ifndef _WIN32
#ifdef H323_H46018
    #include "h460/h460_std18.h"
    H460_FEATURE(Std18);
    H460_FEATURE(Std19);
#endif

#ifdef H323_H46023
    #include "h460/h460_std23.h"
#endif
#endif // _WIN32
#define new PNEW

int main()
{
 // just assume the above works first
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello KevinDTimm, i was trying to make my own fresh copy of it in NetBeans IDE i was trying to make a Makefile and another configure file. But cant understand how everybody does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running [autoscan](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/autoconf/autoscan-Invocation.html) is a good start. It scans your source files and creates an initial configure.ac file (named configure.scan). Also look at [ifnames](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/autoconf/ifnames-Invocation.html#ifnames-Invocation) to scan for your #if's.

Comment: Hello DiggyF, thank you very much. Sounds very interesting, i will try first.

Comment: $ autoscan i ran. And then it created a file called "configure.scan". Is that the file we mostly use as ./configure?

Comment: The configure.scan file is the configure.ac file. It is transformed into a configure script. The autobook ( http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/autobook/autobook_toc.html) has all the details.